# checked iterators in itk using cmake builder

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cmake, itk

I am trying to build itk, however when I try to use sample programs I get the following error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xutility(2761): warning C4996: 'std::_Fill_n': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'
>   2>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xutility(2747) : see declaration of 'std::_Fill_n'

or an error like this:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xutility(2176): warning C4996: 'std::_Copy_impl': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'
>   2>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xutility(2157) : see declaration of 'std::_Copy_impl'
>   2>          c:\users\ayelet\downloads\insighttoolkit-4.8.0\modules\core\common\include\itkImportImageContainer.hxx(72) : see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::copy(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt)' being compiled

basically there seems to be a problem with checked iterators.I lloked up what checked iterators are and eventually got to this link:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh697468(v=vs.110).aspx.
I tried using define ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL in the actual programs but that didn't help. 
I tried compiling the itk libraries with ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=2 and the sample program. To do this I wrote /D_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=2  in cmake_cxx_flags and cmake_c_flags in the cmake-gui. I am still getting the same error.

I thought of trying to stick _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL somewhere in the itk cmakelists but the whole structure seems so complex so I wouldn't know where to put it.

I'm not sure if my syntax in cmake-gui is correct because I couldn't find a single example of setting an option to a specific value in cmake-gui so I don't know if "=" is the correct syntax.(I could only find setting options - like /DWIN32) Than again there could be something else that I'm doing wrong - I just don't know.

Anyone have an idea of what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Often this kind of messages come from mixing up Release/Debug libraries and executables and it's not necessary to set the _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL manually.

I suppose you built ITK both in Debug and Release version (by selecting the drop-down in the Visual Studio menu).
Is it possible that you installed both the version in the same folder? In this case the second one has overwritten the first one (unfortunately the ITK debug libraries don't have the a _d suffix in the name , they have to be in a different folders from the release libraries).

In your sample program, when you run cmake  and you are asked for itk directory, put the itk build directory (instead of the install directory).
To be really sure of what is going on, you can temporarily move the folder with the version you don't want to be included.

Comment: I only built the libraries, The libraries are in different folders. Should the entire project for debug and release be in different folders?

Comment: No, that's not necessary, because Visual Studio automatically creates separate Debug and Release folders for the binaries. Are you using the original build directory of ITK or an install directory?

Comment: Is it the same as your other question? Is it possible that after chaniing cmake directives etc,  you are running "build" instead of "clean/build"?  Sometimes the fastest option is to make a fresh build, from scratch, making sure to use only one version (for example, stick with Release ), check with Hello World, and build the other dependecies and your project in the same version.

Comment: This question is connected to my other question. this question is an isolation version of the othe rproblem. I tried building a fresh build but I still get the same error. I noticed that when I built ITK I got warning LNK4221 on some objects. Could this have something to do with the warnings I get when I try to build a project that uses ITK? Note - the comment I get in warning LNK4221  is "This object file does not define any previously undefined public symbols, so it will not be used by any link operation that consumes this library"

Comment: additionally when building vtk I am getting the following warning : Command line warning D9025: overriding '/W1' with '/w'. Could this have anything to do with my warnings in building itk/using itk libraries?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with that error  and now I don't have any log for checking if I came across it too...